# Запись структуры в файл на языке си

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

Есть кусок программы, осталось только оформить запись в файл, а также после ввода данных мне нужно вновь вывести их на экран, но вместо введенного времени мне выводится адрес в памяти, помогите решить и этот вопрос

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>


struct train
{
    char number[10];
    char path[30];
    int hour;
    int minute;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int N;

    scanf("%i", &N);
    struct train arr[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("Пункт назначения:\n");
        scanf("%s", &arr[i].path);
        printf("Номер поезда:\n");
        scanf("%s", &arr[i].number);
        printf("Час:\n");
        scanf("%i", &arr[i].hour);
        printf("Минуты:\n");
        scanf("%i", &arr[i].minute);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        printf("Пункт назначения %s\n", &arr[i].path );
        printf("Номер поезда %s\n", &arr[i].number);
        printf("Час %d\n", &arr[i].hour);
        printf("Минуты %d\n", &arr[i].minute);
    }

    int time_h;
    int time_min;
    int k = 0;
    printf("Введите часы:\n");
    scanf("%i", &time_h);
    printf("Введите минуты:\n");
    scanf("%i", &time_min);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if((time_h == arr[i].hour) || (time_h == arr[i].hour && time_min == arr[i].minute))
        {
            printf("следующие поезда отправятся в ваше время: %s %s\n ",arr[i].number, arr[i].path );
            k++;
        }
    }
    if(k == 0)
    printf(" Нет подходящих поездов\n");
}
```

Comment: 1) В scanf для строк Вы передаете адрес адреса. 2) Вы в printf передаете адреса, вот она и выводит адреса

Comment: Запись в файл то где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да там все просто -

```
printf("Час %d\n", arr[i].hour);
printf("Минуты %d\n", arr[i].minute);
```

вы должны передавать *значение*, а не адрес.

Но меня заинтриговала строка

```
if((time_h == arr[i].hour) || (time_h == arr[i].hour && time_min == arr[i].minute))
```

Почему так странно? Так вы никогда не проверяете совпадение минут, просто потому, что если совпадает час - то вторую часть проверять нет смысла. Но даже если бы она и проверялась - то первая истинная часть делает результат автоматически истинным.

Ваша проверка эквивалентна проверке

```
if (time_h == arr[i].hour)
```

в то время как вам, как я понимаю, нужна

```
if (time_h == arr[i].hour && time_min == arr[i].minute)
```